# Mountain lion and git-completion

Tags: bash, git, osx-mountain-lion

I have ML with Xcode installed tools (git coming from there).

Later I've installed brew and install bash-completion, but git commands still not auto-completed.

Brew has no such package. Google does not helped. How I can enable git completion support in Mountain Lion?

Comment: Answers containing just links will automatically be converted to comments. The way it's now is fine. Cheers!

Comment: questions like these really belong on ask different, the apple stack exchange site, at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED:**

I've found solution here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55875/how-can-i-get-git-to-autocomplete-e-g-branches-at-the-command-line and it works well.

> I got that by using curl from the URL here:
>
> `curl https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash`
>
> Then I added to my `~/.bash_profile` file the following "execute if it
>   exists" code:
>
> `if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then   . ~/.git-completion.bash; fi`

Comment: +1 - Don't reply to this comment, I will delete it but that is a good answer!

Comment: That should be `-o ~/.git-completion.bash` instead of `-o /.git-completion.bash`

Comment: Also, there needs to be a `;` before the `fi`

Comment: I would suggest changing the URL to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/v1.8.5.2/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash` in order to grab the completion script matching ML's Git version _(1.8.5.2)_.

Comment: Strangely, a Zero Width Non-Joiner character (U+200C) got inserted in the middle of the URL in my last comment.  Try the URL of this link instead: [github/git/git/v1.8.5.2/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/v1.8.5.2/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash).